# How would you detect if WordPress is installed in a subdirectory (not root)?

Tags: directory, installation, subdomains, domain

I want to check if a WordPress installation is working from a subdirectory.

Common methods to achieve this are listed here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

these usually involve changing an index file and requiring WordPress main file from there, perhaps changing rules in htaccess if using Apache - there's no setting up constants from what I can see

so, how would you detect reliably if WordPress is not running from a directory root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the siteurl differs from the home URL:

```
if ( get_option( 'siteurl' ) !== get_option( 'home' ) ) { // whatever
```

This also works if `home` is a subdirectory of the root, with WordPress installed in yet another subdirectory. For example: domain.com/blog (URL) and domain.com/blog/wordpress (siteurl).

Comment: thanks I also thought of that and should have mentioned in OP question -- however, do you think it's reliable in 100% of the cases?

Comment: Yes, because that is the definition of where WordPress is installed. If it differs from the URL, it's a subdirectory install.

Comment: what if it's not a subdirectory install but the URLS are still different? For example sites which have different domains pointing to the same install

Comment: @paul even then both options are the same, and the handling of multiple domains is done somewhere else. Do you have an example where this is not the case?

Comment: for example: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/wordpress_url#to_url - in theory one of those settings could be the temp URL and the other could be the real domain

Comment: @paul - just checked the example - they have to change both values for the temp URL, so it works the same way. I really can't think of any case where this does not work.

Comment: This is not a valid way to check if WordPress is in a subdirectory though. Because siteurl and home can be the same. For instance, domain.com/`site1` is simply the site itself, that it's hosted on `domain.com` is irrelevant. Both `siteurl` and `home` can be set to `https://domain.com/site1`. I am just trying to say that siteurl and home are user input "fields" and they can be the same even if the site is located in a subdirectory. Of course this method will for sure work when the site root is the FQN and WP files are in a subdir.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across for the same question and found another way to figure it out. You can also use the defined Constants from the wp-config.php file.
**SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL** would be the key.

#### Example wp-config excerpt for Multisite settings would be

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'intern.cc.dev');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
```

#### In your code

```
// only run condition, when we are in MS
if( is_multisite() ):

   // check for subfolder installation flag
   if( SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL === false):

      // optional, check if you are on the home WP or a sub WP
      if( get_current_blog_id() > 1):

         // do whatever you need to to here


      endif; // end blog id check
   endif; // end subfolder installation 
endif; // end multisite check
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( '/' !== site_url( '', 'relative') ) {
```